# Change Panel Header text using AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to change the header text using AJAX however it isn't working.

The function below displays images from a mySQL database fine however i can't change simple text on button click.

Please help :)

AJAX CODE:

```
$(function () {
   var images = [],
    index = 0,
    count = 0,
    max = 0;

  $.getJSON("http://testing/api/getimg", function(data) {
    images = data;
    count = images.length;
    max = count - 1;
  });

  $('#getimg1').on('click', function() {

    if (count === 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (index === max) {
        index = 0;
    } else {
        index++;
    }

    //alert(images);
    $('#HTMLPanelHeader').html('CHANGE TEXT TO THIS'); 
    $('#HTMLBox').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + images[index]);

  }); 
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading" id="HTMLPanelHeader">sds</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. Do you have multiple elements with the id `HTMLPanelHeader`?

Comment: Your `count` variable is local to the first function. the second function does not see it and therefore returns early.

Comment: @mikezter Look again. That's an indentation problem.

Comment: @mikezter Thank you, where do you propose i place it then?

Comment: @Mike Thank you but no that is the only element with that ID.. any other solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by *"The function below displays images from a mySQL database fine"*?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the `if (count === 0)` condition. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PatTastic/ukydoa1g/) with that condition commented out, and the text change is working fine. Perhaps there's an issue with the API?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out guys. It wasn't anything to do with my code. It was my browser caching. I disabled the cache and now everything is fine. Thank you for any advice given :)